# Best way to unit test an Opencv Project in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, opencv

What would be the best way to unit test OpenCV projects in Android? Is JUnit the way to go or are there any better ways?

Any links, tutorials etc would be helpful thanks.

Comment: What are you using OpenCV for, the answer probably depends on your actual usage. You can find some ideas for testing graphics code here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150688/how-would-you-unit-test-or-perform-the-most-effective-automated-testing-on-graph

Comment: Im using opencv for eyetracking in an Android project in eclipse.